# My router (Netgear WNR2200) won't accept a static routing in the form of 192.168.1.XXX

Tags: networking, static-routes

My router (Netgear WNR2200) won't accept a static routing in the form of 192.168.1.XXX. I'm trying to set up a route to my server:

[image]

And the settings page. I've tried to limit the DHCP range without effect:

[image]

(I know there's a DHCP reservation at the bottom, that was a test.)

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

The server and router are on the same subnet and as such they do not need a static route.  You are asking your router to route to itself.

You would need a static route if your server was on a separate subnet behind a second router.

```
Router 1 - 192.168.1.1 

Router 2 - 192.168.1.2 with an internal subnet of 192.168.2.1

Server - 192.168.2.5
```

The route would then look like this

> Destination IP Address - 192.168.2.1
>
> IP Subnet Mask - 255.255.255.0
>
> Gateway IP Address - 192.168.1.2
>
> Metric - 1

All this does is tell the router that any IP on the 192.168.2.x subnet is reachable through 192.168.1.2

Comment: To clarify: The destination network would be 192.168.2.0, not 192.168.2.1.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, sorry about that.

Comment: No worries. I figured that's what you meant and wanted to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the subnet mask set to all 1's. While it's technically possible to have a route like this (a host route), my guess is that your router doesn't support a host route and will only accept network routes (a subnet mask of anything less than all 1's).

If you are in fact trying to create a route to a single host then as CoryL stated in his answer, it's unnecessary as the destination ip address is on the same subnet as the router itself.